# usage of that that in "I wanted to ask what is that you would require from me?"

Tags: word-usage, optional-that

I have a sentence where it feels like it would be necessary to use the double that:

> e.g. "I wanted to ask what is **that** you would require from me?"

Is my intuition correct? If yes, please explain why and dissect the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this sentence is incorrect.

While a "that" would make sense in this sentence, it is more common to use "it":

> I wanted to ask **what it is** that you would require from me?

---

This can also take a different form:

> I wanted to ask: **what is it** that you would require from me?

---

@SovereignSun also pointed out that you can use the word "there":

> I wanted to ask: **What is there** that you would require from me?

---

"that" is also correct, but less common in useage:

> I wanted to ask: **what is that** that you would require from me?

Comment: I upvoted your answer, however, you could also use **there** there, **"I wanted to ask: what is there that you would require from me?"** Still it sounds strange.